# Redemption-Outlook VBA Script to move mails with attached msg file from certain sender

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-redemption, mailitem

I am trying to write a VB script for Outlook with Redemption. My task is as follows :

1. Cycle through all emails in my inbox
2. Examine each mail as I go through them
3. If it has an attachment I want to inspect further
4. If the attachment is a msg file and it is from a certain sender then move it to a specific folder

I have determined that Redemption would be the easiest to use as it allows you to inspect attachment without having to save them and open them. I have the following working which will tell me the information for the selected emails attached message.

```
Sub GetAttachmentInfo()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim FolderSrc As MAPIFolder
Set FolderSrc = CreateObject("Outlook.Application"). _
              GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim oRDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession
Set oRDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
oRDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = olNS.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT

Set Inbox = oRDOSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set Mail = olApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
Debug.Print "EntryID: " & Mail.EntryID
Set Mail = oRDOSession.GetMessageFromID(Mail.EntryID)
For Each Msg In FolderSrc.Items
    For Each att In Mail.Attachments
    Debug.Print "Sender: " & att.EmbeddedMsg.SenderEmailAddress
    Debug.Print "Embedded Msg Subject: " & att.EmbeddedMsg
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

I haven't found a way to adopt this to move through every item in my inbox. But have been able to cycle through emails in my inbox to get the subject line.

```
Sub subjectLine()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim Folder As Object
Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim oRDOSession As Redemption.RDOSession
Set oRDOSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
oRDOSession.MAPIOBJECT = olNS.Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT


Set Folder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
For Each Msg In Folder.Items
  Debug.Print (Msg.Subject)
Next
End Sub
```

I know that the basic idea is just a

```
For Each Mail in Inbox.Items    
    If Mail.Attachment >0
         If attachment.sender = "whoever"
             Move to "Specific Folder"
         End If
    End If 
Next
```

Can someone advise on how to do this?

Comment: Is it necessary to work with Redemption?  Instead of "cycling through *all* emails in your inbox", would it suffice to run a procedure against ***incoming*** mail?  If so, take a look at this: [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/).  Note that an important part of it is to specify a parameter for the procedure `(Item As Outlook.MailItem)`, so that Outlook can run the sub on multiple mail items.  Have you managed to run your code at all or is it just copy/pasted from elsewhere?

Comment: That would be ideal. I often get 100 emails every hour. Redemption is not necessary but I am unaware of another way to run the comparisons I need.

Comment: I have run this code successfully. I will be using Outlook Rules to run this script. Currently I am testing it in the VB editor against the whole Inbox to see the effects.

Comment: Alright, so you're saying this code functions correctly on one message; you just need it to run as a rule?  I did something similar recently, so I could basically send an MMS/text message from my phone and the Outlook rule would save the attached data directly to an Access database,  The link I share was the last key to get it working,.

Comment: Sorry I can't (not for free anyway! :-)  ...but everything you need should be in the link in my first comment, or elsewhere on this site.  There's a ton of good info here too: [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx).  Beyond that, I'll be posting my code and detailed explanation within the next day or two, probably to be titled *"Can I send a text message to a database?"*

Comment: Cheers anyway. I will keep an eye out.

Answer (score 0):

In your first script you are already looping through all items in the Inbox, but you never touch them - you are continuously processing the attachment's of the selected message. In the line

```
 For Each att In Mail.Attachments
```

replace Mail with Msg. You will also need to make sure that you are touching an embedded message attachment. Off the top of my head:

```
For Each Msg In FolderSrc.Items
    For Each att In Msg .Attachments
      if att.Type = 5 Then 'olEmbeddedItem
        set embeddedMsg = att.EmbeddedMsg
        Debug.Print "Sender: " & embeddedMsg.SenderEmailAddress
        Debug.Print "Embedded Msg Subject: " & embeddedMsg.Subject
      End If
    Next
Next
```